# Is there a way to get only the IDF values of words using scikit or any other python package?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

I have a text column in my dataset and using that column I want to have a IDF calculated for all the words that are present. TFID implementations in scikit, like *`tfidf` vectorize*, are giving me TFIDF values directly as against just word IDFs. Is there a way to get word IDFs give a set of documents?

Comment: why not just calculate it yourself. It's a simple calculation

Comment: TfidfVectorizer has a `idf_` which you can use after fitting.

Comment: @Usernamenotfound I have been way to addicted to writing my own code to do things for which I know the logic. This has led to me being less efficient than others who know direct functions of libraries. So, I am trying to intentionally not write code unless necessary.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can just use TfidfVectorizer with use_idf=True (default value) and then extract with idf_.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

my_data = ["hello how are you", "hello who are you", "i am not you"]

tf = TfidfVectorizer(use_idf=True)
tf.fit_transform(my_data)

idf = tf.idf_
```

[BONUS] if you want to get the idf value for a particular word:

```
# If you want to get the idf value for a particular word, here "hello"    
tf.idf_[tf.vocabulary_["hello"]]
```

Comment: How would you get the IDF value, for example for the term "not". IDF ("not")= something?

Comment: The attributes "vocabulary_" give you the mapping between the word and the feature indice. You should get the feature indice using vocabulary_ and then get the corresponding value in idf_ using this value.

Comment: Why it is removing 'i' from the vocabulary? I tried setting `stop_words = None, min_df = 1` but didn't help.